# Ajax crawable content .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been trying to figure this one out the past couple of hours but can't get it to work.

I'm tyring to send google to a server side generated version of each page of my AngularJS app.

My angular URLs look like the following:

```
http://localhost:8000/#!/product/123/product+name
```

The static versions generated have the following URL stucture:

```
http://localhost:8000/product/123/product+name
```

So they are both quite similar. I've tried a few different rewrite rule configurations but none have worked so far. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [NC,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

I forgot to say Google and other search engines convert the hash bang URLs into URLs like

```
http://localhost:8000/?_escaped_fragment_=/product/123/product+name
```

Current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/index.html? [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [NC,PT]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where is `escaped_fragment` from ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Updated the question with the explanation for that. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it should work too but when I run curl 'http://localhost:8000/?_escaped_fragment_=/product/123/product+name' I don't get the source of the server generated page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the problem.

Try using `PT` flag instead of `L` flag because of your internal redirect on symlink.
This way, it is re-evaluated

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [NC,PT]
```

---

EDIT: You have to reorder your rules. Your htaccess should look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [NC,PT]

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Cheers for that. No luck though. I'm still seeing the output of the main route with angular tags e.g http://localhost:8000 instead of redirecting to the server side generated page.

Comment: What about combining PT and L ?

Comment: How would I go about doing that just use [NC, PTL]? Thanks!

Comment: No luck. Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: Try using `[NC,R=302]` to debug. You will be redirected to an url. Post the result here as a comment

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://95.85.30.115/bike/88/Basso%2520Loto%2520Veloce%25202013">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 95.85.30.115 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Comment: That looks likt it is working then but CURL just isn't resolving to the page.

Comment: With `PT` flag it should work, this is weird. I've no idea why it fails

Comment: Do you think it will work for crawlers using PT? I'd like to see it work when I test it all the same.

Comment: Well what's the result when you try to reach `http://www.yourdomain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/product/123/product+name` ?

Comment: That brings me to the main route in my angular app. Not redirect at all. If I curl 'http://localhost:8000/?_escaped_fragment_=" I get the snapshot I'm after for the index

Comment: I don't know the behaviour with curl but if you use my code and try to reach an url in browser, you should have it

Comment: Hmm I think it may have been a case of me stupidly leaving the trailing / off the URL when using CURL. Adding it brings up the following in the console 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://95.85.30.115/product/123/product+name">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 95.85.30.115 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Comment: Why do you get a redirection ? Did you write back `[NC,PT]` ? Remove `R` flag if still there

Comment: I'm using what you posted in your answer above and I get the same thing. Is that right?

Comment: You must have a redirect rule in your code. Could you update your question with your current htaccess code ?

Comment: Updated the question with my .htaccess. The URLs do redirect in the browser now as expected. What do you see wrong with what's going on?

Comment: Cool. Still get the same result but I think it's what I'm after. It does a 301 redirect to the right page.

Comment: If you have a 301 redirect it is because of a trailing slash. Is it a problem ? This is a normal behaviour, is it working for you now ?

Comment: I think it's working the way I want it to now yeah. I take it I shouldn't need it to work without the trailing slash? Thank you very much for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: You did it right: avoid duplicate content by removing trailing slash. In both ways, you get the right url. You're welcome, you can accept my answer to "close" your question if that helped you out